# Python Sorting by evaluating conditions, then sorting by separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking to rank-order a dataframe. There are 4 sets of conditions that I want to rank-order on and then for each of those criteria, sort the dataframe by column x "# of people" descending.

My dataframe input:

```
 Product indicator_1 indicator_2 indicator_3 #_people
A        Y            Y          Y           500
B        Y            N          N           600
C        N            Y          N           1000
D        N            Y          N           5000
E        N            Y          Y           200
F        N            N          Y           500
G        N            N          N           600
H        N            N          N           500
```

Expected Output:

```
 Product indicator_1 indicator_2 indicator_3 #_people
B        Y            N          N           600
A        Y            Y          Y           500
D        N            Y          N           5000
C        N            Y          N           1000
E        N            Y          Y           200
G        N            N          N           600
H        N            N          N           500
F        N            N          Y           700
```

For example:

1. If indicator_1 = 'Y', show these rows first. Now that these rows are first, sort them by # of people descending. If indicator_1 = 'N', these rows are not shown at all yet
2. If indicator_2 = 'Y', show these rows second. Sort by # people descending.
3. If indicator_2 = 'N' (same indicator as #2 above) AND indicator_3 = 'N', show these rows third. Sort by # of people descending.
4. If indicator_2 = 'N' (same indicator as #2 above) AND indicator_3 = 'Y', show these rows fourth. Sort by # of people descending.

Another option I am thinking is to create separate sub-dataframes and then union them? Not sure the most efficient option.

Comment: "Hard to explain" actually, not really. Just provide your dataframe (table) show what you have and show what you wish to get.

Comment: Hi cexcelc, it would be helpful if you would include an example dataframe that you wish to do this on, and what you expect your output to look like. In its current state, your question is at risk of being closed.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to build a new column that indicates priority and then sort the dataframe by that column and then people descending

Comment: Hi @abhg I have modified my post

Comment: Hi @d_kennetz I have modified my post

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your data, the expected output, you have a `700`, where is it from?

The problem you tried to solve is not a one-step sorting problem. The conditions you gave are contradicted at some level:

```
1st condition indicator_1=="Y", you want to ascending sort Num_people, 
2nd condition indicator_1=="N", you want to descending sort indicator_2
```

This is my approach. You need to do two step: 
1. Sort Indicator_1 first
2. Select Indicator1==Y, for one sort; then Indicator1==N for another sort.

```
import pandas as pd
Product_ = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
indicator_1 = ["Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N"]
indicator_2 = ["Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N"]
indicator_3 = ["Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N"]
Num_people = [500, 600, 1000, 5000, 200, 500, 600, 500]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Product_": Product_, "indicator_1": indicator_1, "indicator_2": indicator_2, "indicator_3": indicator_3, "Num_people": Num_people})
# print(df)
#  Product indicator_1 indicator_2 indicator_3 #_people
# A        Y            Y          Y           500
# B        Y            N          N           600
# C        N            Y          N           1000
# D        N            Y          N           5000
# E        N            Y          Y           200
# F        N            N          Y           500
# G        N            N          N           600
# H        N            N          N           500

temp = df.sort_values(["indicator_1", "Num_people"], ascending = [False, False])

temp_1 = temp[temp.indicator_1=="Y"]
temp = pd.concat([temp_1, temp[temp.indicator_1=="N"].sort_values(["indicator_2", "indicator_3", "Num_people"], ascending = [False, True, False])])
print(temp)
```

The output is:

```
  Product_ indicator_1 indicator_2 indicator_3  Num_people
1        B           Y           N           N         600
0        A           Y           Y           Y         500
3        D           N           Y           N        5000
2        C           N           Y           N        1000
4        E           N           Y           Y         200
6        G           N           N           N         600
7        H           N           N           N         500
5        F           N           N           Y         500
```

Hope this helps.